# Express as middleware to Server Side Rendering of my multi-languages angular app

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I used express as a middleware to serve my angular application (SSR), but as I used internationalisation (spanish & english) on my angular app, I prefixed my urls with /sp and /en to switch between both distributed forlder for both languages.

The prefix has just to be taken into account to pick the right folder and then forward the request to the right angular dist folder, but once done, I have to remove the language prefix /sp /en on every url before rendering the result.

Here's what I has

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');    

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'en')); // <-- the default language I want to set

app.namespace('/en/', function(){
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'en'));
    req.url = req.url.slice(4); // <--  here's how I tried to edit the request's url
    res.render('index', { req });
  })
});

app.namespace('/sp/', function(){
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'sp'));
    req.url = req.url.slice(4); // <-- same workaround here
    res.render('index', { req });
  })
});
```

But it doesn't work as expected as I still have the language prefix on the url of the request I forward to my dist files.

What did I miss?
Thank you

Comment: I think you should keep the URL as is and just set base-href to '/en' and '/sp' in the 2 index.html files

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong here, the only way the browser will change the URL in this scenario is if the server returns a redirect response i.e. `30x`. However, based on your code if the server removes the lang prefix and redirects they effectively lose the preference from the previous response.

Given each user will most likely get to choose their preferred language, and the fact the server has to *remember* what they chose, it seems logical to me that this needs to be a *session*-based option.

I've no idea as to what backend you are using to store data but a good place to start would be to look at [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), it uses an in-memory store by default to get you started but supports [various](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) production-ready ones out the box.